# Prove that $\int|f − g| = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} μ(F_t △ G_t) dt.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ and $g$ be integrable functions on a measure space $(X,Σ,μ).$ For each
$t ∈ \mathbb{R},$ consider the sets
$F_t =\{x∈X :f(x)>t\},
G_t =\{x∈X :g(x)>t\}.$
Prove that
$\int|f − g| = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} μ(F_t △ G_t) dt.$

Here $A △ B = (A $\ B) ∪ (B \ A) denotes symmetric difference of sets.

I am having a lot of difficulty figuring out where to start on this problem.  Some direction would be awesome.  Its a past qual problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Fubini will probably be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notation:** For $Y\subset X$, let $1_Y:X\to \Bbb R$ defined by $1_Y(y) = \begin{cases}1 \,\,\,\,\text{ if }y\in Y
\\ 0 \,\,\,\,\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$

---

$$F_t △ G_t = \{ x: f(x) > t \ge g(x)\} \cup \{ x: g(x) > t \ge f(x)\} 
$$
and the intersection of these sets is empty, so
$$\mu(F_t △ G_t)
= \mu(\{ x: f(x) > t \ge g(x)\})
+  \mu(\{ x: g(x) > t \ge f(x)\});
\\
\int_\Bbb R dt \mu(\{ x: f(x) > t \ge g(x)\}) 
= \int_X d\mu \left(\int_\Bbb R dt \{ t: f(x) > t \ge g(x)\}\right)
\\= \int_X d\mu (f(x)-g(x))1_{f(x)>g(x)} $$
using the Fubini theorem in the middle. Do the same thing with the other part and you are done.